# ADS62P22 ADC output format

Tags: adc, datasheet

I am having trouble interpreting the Output Data Section of the [datasheet for the ADS62P22](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads62p22.pdf) ADC.

Page 56 includes the following description:

> Output Data Format
>
> Two output data formats are supported - 2s complement and straight binary. They can be selected using the serial interface register bit DATA FORMAT or controlling the SEN pin in parallel configuration mode.
>
> In the event of an input voltage overdrive, the digital outputs go to the appropriate full-scale level. **For a positive overdrive, the output code is 0x7FF in offset binary output format, and 0x3FF in the 2s complement output format. For a negative input overdrive, the output code is 0x000 in offset binary output format and 0x400 in the 2s complement output format.**

(emphasis mine)

Based on this description, the full code range for the straight binary output format is 0x000 to 0x7FF or 0 to 2047 in decimal. The full code range for the 2s complement format is 0x400 to 0x3FF, or -1024 to 1023 in decimal. Both of these ranges have a total of 2048 codes, which only requires 11 bits.

But this is a 12 bit ADC. What happened to the other half of the codes?

Comment: Most likely it's just an error in the datsheet. You could ask on the TI website ("MyTI" forums, I think) and probably get a response from a TI apps engineer.

Comment: I suspected a datasheet error, but wanted to get some more eyes on it to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I reached out to TI, and they confirmed that this is an error with their datasheet.

https://e2e.ti.com/support/data-converters/f/73/p/796746/2948887#2948887